# Visual studio 2015 Cordova Project to include staging and production configuration files

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, azure, visual-studio-cordova

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Cordova to connect to Azure Mobile Services.
I setup "staging" and "production" of Mobile Service,

ex:

```
https://mystaging.azuremobileservices.net  

https://myproduction.azuremobileservices.net
```

and I use following code in staging deployment

```
var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient('https://mystaging.azuremobileservices.net', 'mykey');

// var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient('https://myproduction.azuremobileservices.net', 'mykey');
```

and the following for production deployment

```
// var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient('https://mystaging.azuremobileservices.net', 'mykey');

var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient('https://myproduction.azuremobileservices.net', 'mykey');
```

Do I have to manually comment and uncomment the code in order to have different deployment configuration?

I can't find no where to setup the testing/staging/production config in Visual Studio 2015 RC Cordova Project.

Could someone have some suggestion for this configuration management in VS2015 Cordova?

thanks a lot.